# Suddenly can't add events in Jorte?

Tags: jorte

Just today I've been unable to add events in Jorte. I can only add in Google calendars and then sync. 
Anybody know what's going on? 
I'm so sad!

Comment: Did you update it?  Are you seeing an error message?

Answer (score 1):

In settings, Click Default Calendar to select a default calendar for new events. Then, when you click new event, there is an option for calendars. Make sure PC Sync is selected and not Exchange.